# Change away time in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

How can I change the time I am away for, before teams changes my status to away.

Or even deactivate it completely.

It was pretty easy to find in skype but U cannot find anything in setting for tams, and google had nothing that seemed useful either.

It seems to change to away after around 5 mins, and also changes to away if I'm watching a video or in a call, and do not use the mouse or keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this. The best work-around I have found is using a program like Caffeine or some other software mouse 'jiggler' to keep the device from going idle and showing 'Away'.