# How to create a batch script for mouse movement to prevent MS Teams status away?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, office365, microsoft-teams

Looks like MS Teams does not provide a way to set duration for showing away as described in https://superuser.com/a/1621012/849717. How to create a batch script to periodically move mouse, say a couple of pixels away and back to original position, so it will prevent MS Teams from showing status away?

Comment: search for `move mouse powershell` in your favorite search engine and click the first link. Invoke the script through scheduled tasks, or have it constantly running in the background. Or use an approach as described here https://www.addictivetips.com/web-conferencing/microsoft-teams-away-status/

Comment: Already tried approach from the link. It doesn't work. That link is meant to prevent away while working on other apps.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].